# QML TableView get data from specific cell (selected row + specific column)

Tags: qt, qml, tableview

I have QML `TableView` with `QSqlQueryModel`. I need to select any row and get data from every column of table to separate `TextField`.

Here is abonentstable.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QSqlQueryModel>

class AbonentsSqlModel : public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AbonentsSqlModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    void setQuery(const QString &query, const QSqlDatabase &db = QSqlDatabase());
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const { return m_roleNames; }

private:
    void generateRoleNames();
    QHash<int, QByteArray> m_roleNames;
};
```

abonentstable.cpp:

```
#include "abonentstable.h"

#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QSqlField>

AbonentsSqlModel::AbonentsSqlModel(QObject *parent) : QSqlQueryModel(parent)
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("data_base.sqlite");
    db.open();
}

void AbonentsSqlModel::setQuery(const QString &query, const QSqlDatabase &db)
{
    QSqlQueryModel::setQuery(query, db);
    generateRoleNames();
}

void AbonentsSqlModel::generateRoleNames()
{
    m_roleNames.clear();
    for( int i = 0; i < record().count(); i ++) {
        m_roleNames.insert(Qt::UserRole + i + 1, record().fieldName(i).toUtf8());
    }
}

QVariant AbonentsSqlModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    QVariant value;

    if(role < Qt::UserRole) {
        value = QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
    }

    else {
        int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
        QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
        value = QSqlQueryModel::data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Table.qml:

```
TableView {
    id: table

    model: abonents

    ....

    TableViewColumn {
        delegate: Text {
            text: " " + model.name + " " + model.surname
            font.pointSize: 20
        }    
        width: 575
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        delegate: Text {
            text: " " + model.phone
            font.pointSize: 20
        }    
        width: 575
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        delegate: Text {
            text: " " + model.ip_address
            font.pointSize: 20
        }    
        width: 525
    }
}
```

And some text fields:

```
TextField {
    id:  leftText
}

TextField {
     id:  centerText
}

TextField {
    id:  rightText
}
```

This sqlite table has 4 columns, and I need to get data from selected row to those text fields: 2 columns to left, 1 to center and 1 to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user clicks a valid row it is emitted the `clicked(int row)` signal. Then, you can get the values for that `row`, format the text depending on your requirements and set the values in the three `TextField`. For example, in your case:

```
TableView {
    id: table

    model: abonents

    ... (your TableViewColumn components) ...    

    onClicked: {
        leftText.text = abonents.get(row).name + " " + libraryModel.get(row).surname;
        centerText.text = abonents.get(row).phone;
        rightText.text = abonents.get(row).ip_address;
    }
}
```

Please, let me please use my [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682420/display-several-roles-in-one-column-of-tableview) to show you a complete example:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    title: "Table View Example"

    TableView {
        y: 70
        width: 500

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "title"
            title: "Title"
            width: 100
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "author"
            title: "Author"
            width: 100
        }

        TableViewColumn{
            width: 300
            delegate: Text {
                text: model.title + " "  + model.author
                font.family: "Courier New"
                font.pixelSize: 18
                color: "red"
            }
        }

        onClicked: {
            leftText.text = libraryModel.get(row).title + " " + libraryModel.get(row).author;
            centerText.text = libraryModel.get(row).title;
            rightText.text = libraryModel.get(row).author;
        }

        model: libraryModel

        ListModel {
            id: libraryModel
            ListElement {
                title: "A Masterpiece"
                author: "Gabriel"
            }
            ListElement {
                title: "Brilliance"
                author: "Jens"
            }
            ListElement {
                title: "Outstanding"
                author: "Frederik"
            }
        }
    }

    TextField {
        id:  leftText
    }

    TextField {
        id:  centerText
        anchors.left: leftText.right
    }

    TextField {
        id:  rightText
        anchors.left: centerText.right
    }
}
```

Comment: How when using TableView in Qt Quick Controls 2?