# QML TableView get row clicked with QtQuick.Controls 2

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I've searched a lot on the net but I didn't find an answer and that's something really strange since I suppose it's a basic functionality most people should use (probably I don't understand how to correctly use *TableView* with *QtQuick.Controls 2*).

Tha problem is: I would like to know on which row I clicked and I want to access data of a particular column of that row (something like TableView.get(row, column)). In *QtQuick.Controls 1.4* there are functions that allow me to access the rows ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956108/qml-tableview-get-data-from-specific-cell-selected-row-specific-column)) but I cannot find any for *QtQuick.Control 2*. Also there aren't the *selection:* and *itemDelegate:* that would be useful. How can implement these things in *QtQuick.Controls 2*?

I am using Qt 5.15.0 with MinGw. I have datas from a database that are passed to QML with ***QAbstractTableModel***.

.cpp model

```
#include "archiviosqlmodel.h"
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QDebug>

ArchivioSqlModel::ArchivioSqlModel(QObject *parent) :
    QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
    db_4= QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QStringLiteral("QSQLITE"), "def.db");
        db_4.setDatabaseName("def.db");
    if (!db_4.isOpen())
        db_4.open();

    QSqlQuery query(db_4);
    query.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS A (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, B INTEGER, C CHAR(5), D CHAR(5), E CHAR(5));");
    query.exec("INSERT INTO A (ID, B, C, D, E) VALUES (1, 2, 'AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC')");
    query.exec("INSERT INTO A (ID, B, C, D, E) VALUES (2, 4, 'DDDDD', 'FFFFF', 'QQQQQ')");
    query.exec("INSERT INTO A (ID, B, C, D, E) VALUES (3, 5, 'EEEEE', 'GGGGG', 'HHHHH')");


    model.setQuery("SELECT * FROM A", db_4);

    qDebug() << "Row Count " << model.rowCount() << "Column count " << model.columnCount();
}

ArchivioSqlModel::~ArchivioSqlModel()
{
    db_4.close();
}

QVariant ArchivioSqlModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        if(orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
        {
            switch (section)
            {
            case 0:
                return tr("ID");
            case 1:
                return tr("A");
            case 2:
                return tr("A");
            case 3:
                return tr("A");
            case 4:
                return tr("A");
            }
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}

int ArchivioSqlModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid())
        return 0;
    return model.rowCount();
}

int ArchivioSqlModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid())
        return 0;
    return model.columnCount();
}

QVariant ArchivioSqlModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    QVariant value;
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();
    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole && index.row() >= 0 && index.row() < rowCount()
            && index.column() >= 0 && index.column() < columnCount())
    {
        QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), index.column());
        value = model.data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
        return value;//QString("data %1-%2").arg(index.row()).arg(index.column());
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

.h model

```
    #include <QSqlQueryModel>


class ArchivioSqlModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ArchivioSqlModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    ~ArchivioSqlModel() override;

signals:
    void queryStrChanged();

public slots:

private:
    const static char* COLUMN_NAMES[];
    const static char* SQL_SELECT;

    QSqlDatabase db_4;
    QSqlQueryModel model;

    QHash<int, QByteArray> m_roleNames;

};
```

main.qml

```
 import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import Archive 1.0
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        x: 62
        y: 106
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "#000022"
        border.width: 0
        anchors.fill:parent

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangleBack
            x: 10
            y: 406
            width: 64
            height: 64
            color: "#000033"
            radius: 20
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 10
            border.width: 2
            border.color: "#ffffff"

            MouseArea {
                id: mouseAreaBack
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    if (stackView.depth > 1)
                        stackView.pop()
                }
                onPressed: {
                    rectangleBack.width = 64 - 4
                    rectangleBack.height = 64 - 4
                }
                onReleased: {
                    rectangleBack.width = 64
                    rectangleBack.height = 64
                }
            }
        }

        Text {
            id: textArchive
            height: 25
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Datas:")
            font.family: "Arial"
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.bold: true
            fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 10
            font.pixelSize: 14
        }

        ArchivioSqlModel {
            id: archiviomodel
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangle1
            color: "#000022"
            radius: 10
            border.width: 2
            border.color: "#ffffff"
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 5
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 5
            anchors.bottom: rectangleBack.top
            anchors.bottomMargin: 10
            anchors.top: textArchive.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 10

            TableView {
                id: tableViewid
                anchors.leftMargin: 5
                anchors.bottomMargin: 5
                anchors.rightMargin: 5
                anchors.topMargin: 5

                columnWidthProvider: function (column) { return 100; }
                rowHeightProvider: function (column) { return 60; }
                anchors.fill: parent
                topMargin: columnsHeader.implicitHeight



                model: archiviomodel
                ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar{}
                ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{}
                clip: true



                delegate: Rectangle {
                    Text {
                        id: textId
                        text: display
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        anchors.margins: 10
                        color: 'black'
                        font.pixelSize: 15
                        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    }

                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        onClicked: {
                            console.log("prova:" + textId.text)
                        }
                    }
                }


                Rectangle { // mask the headers
                    z: 3
                    color: "#000033"
                    y: tableViewid.contentY
                    x: tableViewid.contentX
                    width: tableViewid.leftMargin
                    height: tableViewid.topMargin
                }

                Row {
                    id: columnsHeader
                    y: tableViewid.contentY
                    z: 2
                    Repeater {
                        model: tableViewid.columns > 0 ? tableViewid.columns : 1
                        Label {
                            width: tableViewid.columnWidthProvider(modelData)
                            height: 35
                            text: archiviomodel.headerData(modelData, Qt.Horizontal)
                            color: '#ffffff'
                            font.pixelSize: 15
                            padding: 10
                            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter

                            background: Rectangle {
                                radius: 10
                                color: "#000022"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                ScrollIndicator.horizontal: ScrollIndicator { }
                ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }

            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangleOpenlap
            x: 10
            y: 406
            width: 64
            height: 64
            color: "#000033"
            radius: 20
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 10
            border.width: 2
            border.color: "#ffffff"

            MouseArea {
                id: mouseAreaOpenlap
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("Rows")
                }
                onPressed: {
                    rectangleOpenlap.width = 64 - 4
                    rectangleOpenlap.height = 64 - 4
                }
                onReleased: {
                    rectangleOpenlap.width = 64
                    rectangleOpenlap.height = 64
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "archiviosqlmodel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<ArchivioSqlModel>("Archive", 1, 0, "ArchivioSqlModel");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide a complete minimal example that we can paste into a project and run? i.e. add the missing includes, imports and Window.

Comment: The #includes for the C++ code. :)

Comment: @Mitch done, I hope I haven't missed something else :P Thanks for the patience

Comment: Please try to copy this code into a project yourself and see if it runs. If it doesn't run for you, it won't for others. For some reason there are missing and misplaced double quotes throughout the code.

Comment: @Mitch I'm sorry again. Changed the file, tested it and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access data from the model, you can use the model context property and the built-in [display role](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames):

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        console.log(model.display)
    }
}
```

Model data can be [set](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#changing-model-data) in a similar way.

The above is basically a shorter way of the following:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        console.log(row, column, tableViewid.model.data(tableViewid.model.index(row, column)))
    }
}
```

The code above uses [index()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index) to create an index that can then be passed to [data()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data)

The row and column properties are provided to each [delegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html#delegate-prop).

This is also useful if you need to get data from the model from outside the delegate, for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks Mitch this was exactly what I was searching for :) Thanks for the patience!