# How to implement Selectable future of TableView QtQuick.Controls 1.4 in TableView QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Tags: qt, qml

How could implement row selection in `QtQuick.Controls.TableView > 2`? in the version 1 by default we have it:

[image]

And we could select the entire items in a row by clicking on one of them. How could this be implemented on version 2 of `QtQuick.Controls.TableView`?.

I checked those:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62636354/9248466
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwukO5Vusv8

But still, I failed to implement it. Here is my attempt to implementing:

```js
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

Window {
  width: 640
  height: 480
  visible: true
  title: qsTr("Hello World")


  TableView {
    id: table
    anchors.fill: parent
    columnWidthProvider: function(column)
    {
      return 100;
    }

    model: TableModel {
      TableModelColumn { display: "name" }
      TableModelColumn { display: "color" }

      rows: [
        {
          "name": "cat",
          "color": "black"
        },
        {
          "name": "dog",
          "color": "brown"
        },
        {
          "name": "bird",
          "color": "white"
        }
      ]
    }

    delegate: ItemDelegate {
      readonly property color defaultTextColor: "orange";
      readonly property color defaultBackgroundColor: "#222";
      readonly property color defaultBorderColor: "black";
      readonly property color selectedTextColor: "white";
      readonly property color selectedBackgroundColor: "#997300";
      readonly property color selectedBorderColor: "cyan";

      property bool select: table.currentIndex === index
      property color textColor: defaultTextColor;
      property color backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor;
      property color borderColor: defaultBorderColor;

      background: Rectangle
      {
        anchors.fill: parent;
        color: select ? selectedBackgroundColor : backgroundColor; // <----
        border.color: borderColor;
        border.width: 0.5;
      }
      contentItem: Text
      {
        id: contentItemText
        text: model.display;
        clip: true;
        color: textColor;
        anchors.centerIn: parent;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My environment:

- OS: Fedora 34
- Compiler: GCC 11.2.1
- Qt: 5.15.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no currentIndex property in the QtQuick TableView so you must create and implement that property, in this case I will implement currentRow that will change when any item in the row is clicked.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TableView {
        id: table

        property int currentRow: -1

        anchors.fill: parent
        columnWidthProvider: function(column) {
            return 100;
        }

        model: TableModel {
            rows: [{
                "name": "cat",
                "color": "black"
            }, {
                "name": "dog",
                "color": "brown"
            }, {
                "name": "bird",
                "color": "white"
            }]

            TableModelColumn {
                display: "name"
            }

            TableModelColumn {
                display: "color"
            }

        }

        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            id: itemDelegate

            readonly property color defaultTextColor: "orange"
            readonly property color defaultBackgroundColor: "#222"
            readonly property color defaultBorderColor: "black"
            readonly property color selectedTextColor: "white"
            readonly property color selectedBackgroundColor: "#997300"
            readonly property color selectedBorderColor: "cyan"
            property bool select: TableView.view.currentRow === row
            property color textColor: defaultTextColor
            property color backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor
            property color borderColor: defaultBorderColor

            background: Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: select ? selectedBackgroundColor : backgroundColor
                border.color: borderColor
                border.width: 0.5
            }

            contentItem: Text {
                id: contentItemText

                text: model.display
                clip: true
                color: textColor
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }

           MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: itemDelegate.TableView.view.currentRow = row
            }

        }

    }

}
```